# Paypal tax_rate variable is not working

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated Paypal standard payment in my php website now i required to send tax in Paypal payment so i have pass `tax_rate` variable in paypal form, all are working nice but tax is not send in paypal.

My Paypal form code is below.

```
<form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL;?>" name="paypalForm" method="post">                 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_EMAIL;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo $mainObj->listing_title;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" id="item_number" value="<?php echo $booking_id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $mainObj->user_id.'__'.$objExtraPostData->message_to_host.'__'.$objExtraPostData->host_call.'__'.$vat.'__'.$mainObj->pay_price.'__'.$guest_invite_id.'__'.$host_invite_id.'__'.$review_guest_invite_id.'__'.$review_host_invite_id; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php echo $mainObj->pay_price;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" id="discount_amount" value="<?php echo $discount_price;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="<?php echo $vat;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo DEFAULT_PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo SITE_MOD."nct-paypal/thankyou.php";?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo SITE_MOD."nct-paypal/failed.php";?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo SITE_MOD."nct-paypal/notify.php";?>">
 </form>
```

Comment: Which values for $vat you tried? Maybe you've used a comma instead of a point

Comment: Sorry, how exactly is it `not working`? Does this HTML form not appear? Does the transaction fail? Is there a PHP error?

Comment: I mean tax is not pass in paypal

Comment: i have used 12 for vat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the tax_rate can be used with your payment type. In addition, it might be better when you set your tax rate in your account profile as described beneath.

> Transaction-based tax override variable. Set this variable to a percentage that applies to the amount multiplied by the quantity selected during checkout. This value overrides any tax settings set in your account profile. Allowable values are numbers 0.001 through 100. Valid only for Buy Now and Add to Cart buttons. Default – Profile tax settings, if any, apply.

Comment: My payment type is paypal standard and tax_rate variable support my payment type.i have set 12% vat but can't working.